# Printing elements of a char array with numbes and letters

Tags: c, char

I am trying to print out the elements of my char array which consists of both numbers and letters. My code is:

```
char *receiveInput(char *s) {
    scanf("%99s", s);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char str[100], inp[50] = "";
    printf("Enter string");
    receiveInput(str);
    char cToStr[3];
    int num = 3;
    char c = (char)(num);
    cToStr[0] = c;
    cToStr[1] = str[0];
    cToStr[2] = '\0';
    strcat(inp, cToStr);
    printf("%s\n", inp);
    return 0;
}
```

Lets say str in `"hey"`, `inp` should contain and print `"3h`" but instead it just prints 'h' when cToStr[0] = c (which is a char 3).

How do I print the elements which contain both numbers and letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 3 is not the same as character '3'. For example in the ASCII table character '3' has integer code in hex `0x33` while in the EBCDIC table it has code `0xf3`.

You can write

```
  int num = 3;
  char c = num + '0';
  cToStr[0] = c;
```

provided that num us less than 10.

Comment: By the way, the C specification guarantees that the digits from `0` to `9` *must* appear in order in the character set in use. And, incidentally, not so for `A` to `Z`; so `'0` + digit` will always show the correct output digit, but `'A' + digit` might not do so.

Comment: Nitpick: ascii '3' is actually 0x33

Comment: What if i want to concatenate a number which is greater than 9  with a char. Lets say the number 25 and char 'g', how would i concatenate the two to be '25g'?

Answer (score 1):

C uses ASCII encoding for characters/strings. ASCII value 3 is a non-printable character. If you want the character '3' you need to use integer value 51. Refer to http://www.asciitable.com/.